# $95\text%$ confidence interval question

Tags: probability

In a study of $205$ adults, the mean heart rate was $75$ beats per minute. Assume the population of heart rates is known to be approximately normal with a standard deviation of $8$ beats per minute. What is the $95\text{%}$ confidence interval for the mean beats per minute?

*I know confidence interval is an estimated range of population, but not quite sure how to find it.

would it be $75 -(\text{upper limit})(8)$

would it be $75 +(\text{upper limit})(8)$

how do i find the upper limit, assuming i am correct?

Answer (score 0):

$95\%$ of the population will have a heart rate within two standard deviations of the mean. So you just need to find the interval consisting of all numbers that are less than two standard deviations away from the mean.